# Why I'm getting flag penality for flagging something wrong what got edited to something right?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I have reviewed an answer today which just was an exact copy of the code posted by OP, nothing else added to it.

I flagged it as not an answer.

2 hours later the user who posted it, edited it, outside of the grace period. The answer was edited to something to be an answer, and could at least be interpreted as such.

Then 5 minutes later my flag was declined with the note that it attempts to answer the question and should not have been flagged as NAA.

I can't flag again. And just copy pasting the question isn't an attempt to answer the question, is it?

So why was it declined? Is that "crime" just a crime for as long as it is happening? Should I remove the flag as soon as the problem is fixed? (Is there even a way to undo flags to prevent me from getting flag lock in such a situation?)

Comment: I'd be curious to see what post you flagged exactly. Aside from whether that original version should have been flagged, it will happen that you flag a post, it gets edited, and then your flag is declined. You may even have a flagged mistakenly declined for whatever reason. It happens to everyone (including diamond-mods). It certainly happened to me before.

Comment: Ah downvoting me, because... ?

Comment: This reads like a rant and probably needs to be rewritten.

Comment: @Zaibis Do you have the link to the answer you flagged?

Comment: Downvoting because you are presuming you are correct and other users who reviewed are wrong, and while that may turn out to be the case, some civility and giving the benefit of the doubt goes a long way. I mean, did you come here to rant, to tell us you are correct, or to *ask* if you are correct or not? Where's the link? Why profanities? Why are your "pissed off" with a single declined flag? Sure, disagree with it, but if you get "pissed off" at such simple things then perhaps you need to step back and evaluate what's important.

Comment: Keep in mind that in evaluating flags you generally can't expect those who handle it to make the same interpretation you made based on the flagged content alone. They'll see a code block which possibly might be an answer. What they miss out on is that it's exactly the same as the question (if that's the case). In such cases you might want to go for something that's more clear and use an "other" flag where you have the room to explain what it is you saw, and why you say it's not an answer.

Comment: Also keep in mind that some helpful flags help feed into the audit selection system, so marking a flag as helpful in some cases could lead to the post being selected as a "known bad" audit.  If it is misleading then users will be complaining about failing an audit for a post that looked good.

Comment: I'm "pissed" of because that happende now already the 3rd time in the last weeks. And thanks for the edit of my in anger writen but seriously asking question. Here is the link to the revision: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27271852/revisions

Comment: Even in its first revision it seems to be an attempt at an answer. Am I overlooking something? You say it was edited outside the grace period. Do you mean inside?

Comment: @Bart I'm guessing they mean that the revision could be seen that it was the initial version that was flagged... maybe. But I'm probably wrong, since I always am. :)

Comment: Might be @bluefeet, but even in that case I'd say NAA wouldn't have been correct. Then again, you have the diamond, I don't :D

Comment: @Bart agreed, which was probably why it was declined.

Comment: @Bart Yeah, in the first version it could be an attempt to answer a question. But if you compare the code with the question you will notice, the first code (which got changed drasticly) Was in the first version nothing the the code of the question. thats the point.

Comment: @Zaibis When answers are reviewed - we review the content of the answer. Does it look like an answer...yes. That would be why the flag got declined.  If you believe that there is more to it, then you should use a custom "other" flag explaining why you think a moderator needs to intervene with the answer.  But for this answer, it really isn't something a moderator needs to be involved in.  You should downvote, comment, etc and move along.

Comment: But there we go then @Zaibis. That's not a reason to flag. That's going to get declined. It's a reason to leave a (constructive) comment for the author of the answer or to simply downvote. No matter how lousy the attempt, it was an attempt.

Comment: So just citing a question is a answer? A lousy one but it is one? Just that I get it right for future purpose.

Comment: It is not citing the question. It says *"With Visual Studio, I get compile errors without changing *p to int (*p)[3]"* ... after which the code is shown with the change. That (to me at least) seems to imply an attempt at an answer. How great an attempt is up for debate, but it is one.

Comment: Ok, I've got it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though only the handling moderator can confirm this, I'm not at all convinced it's the subsequent edits that got your flag declined. Even in its first iteration the answer you flagged was an attempt at an answer. How great an attempt is debatable, but it is not a simply copy-paste of the question. If it's merely bad, or if the "answer" doesn't really change anything, then downvote. Leave a comment. But don't flag. Perhaps we should rename the flag to NAAAAA (Not an attempt at an answer), because that's what it's really for.

But let's for the sake of argument say that you're right. Someone just duplicated the question, perhaps with a word or two added to it but there's no real attempt at an answer. You could flag that as NAA. But you might want to be careful. Ask yourself this: "Is it clear, without looking at the question, that this is not an answer". If the answer isn't a definite "yes", you might want to reconsider your flag. Perhaps go for he "other" option instead and clearly state what it is you see and how this isn't even a genuine attempt at an answer. Success isn't guaranteed, but your chances are better.

Comment: I feel like writing a song with _NAAAAA, NAAAAA, NAAAAA_ in it now.  Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @bluefeet https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IoyvvEWHodk

Comment: I knew that was coming. :)

Answer (score 2):

> I flagged it as not an answer

That was the wrong thing to do in this case, as it was an attempt to answer the question.
However bad an attempt it was, there is still *an "attempt" to answer*.

**"it is not an answer" flag states**:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the
>   question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question,
>   or deleted altogether.

Even if what you say is true, and they just copy/pasted the OP's code, it was an attempt to answer the question - it was just a bad answer or bad attempt.

I know the definition can be a bit confusing, but if you agree it was a terrible answer, it was useless, all it did was copy/paste the OP's code, then we have defined that is was a (bad) "answer".

"Not an answer" is for things such as:

- "thanks this helped me too"
- "I also have this issue, mine does this, how do I.." (should be
  another question)
- "This question sucks!!" (should be deleted)

Those are logically "not an attempt to answer", whereas some code relating to the question and OP's code, is an attempt to answer.

So this scenario was not a reason to flag, and in these scenarios you should downvote the answer, and leave a comment explaining to the answerer suggestions as to why their answer is not good, and possibly how to improve it.